# How do I get the generalized screen size?

Tags: android

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html states:

> Terms and concepts
>
> Screen size Actual physical size,
>   measured as the screen's diagonal. For
>   simplicity, Android groups all actual
>   screen sizes into four generalized
>   sizes: small, normal, large, and extra
>   large.

How do I programmatically get the generalized size of the device screen?  The method or property I am looking for will return one of:  small, normal, large, and extra large.  (or const/enums that can be mapped to those)

Thanks.

-mz

Comment: Read this May this help you http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/01/plan-design-in-best-way-for-multiple.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`screenLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#screenLayout) in the `Configuration` object.

Comment: The code for this is shown in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015094/determine-device-screen-category-small-normal-large-xlarge-using-code