# How to programatically determine which XML layout my Android apps is using?

Tags: android, android-layout

How do I programatically determine which layout (layout-normal, layout-large, etc.) my app is currently using? I see the getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics) call but it seems to only deal with screen density but not necessary which layout the app is using. I need the info since I need to programatically change some of the positioning of views dynamically at runtime.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 32):

An extremely easy way to do this, is by setting a id and tag to the parent layout and in your `onCreate()`, you can `findViewById()` and `getTag()`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/my_activity_view"
    android:tag="big_screen" >
        // misc views~
</RelativeLayout>
```

And then, in your `onCreate` method,

```
if(findViewById(R.id.my_activity_view).getTag().equals("big_screen")) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: You should be able to skip the tag test if you just give the parent layout in each of the variations a different ID.

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem. If you're using `layout`/`layout-sw600dp`/`layout-sw720dp`, the following ended working for me:

```
Configuration config = activity.getResources().getConfiguration();

if (config.smallestScreenWidthDp >= 720) {
  // sw720dp code goes here
}
else if (config.smallestScreenWidthDp >= 600) {
  // sw600dp code goes here
}
else {
  // fall-back code goes here
}
```

Comment: Yes, this should be the valid answer.

Answer (score 3):

Following code will help you. I just printed corresponding screen size or density category. U can do whatever you want!

```
//Determine screen size
    if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) 
    {     
        Log.d("Screen Size: ", "LARGE");

    }
    else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &      Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL) {     
        Log.d("Screen Size: ", "NORMAL");

    } 
    else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &      Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL) {     
        Log.d("Screen Size: ", "SMALL");
    }
    else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &      Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE) {     
        Log.d("Screen Size: ", "XLARGE");
    }
    else {
        Log.d("Screen Size: ","UNKNOWN_CATEGORY_SCREEN_SIZE");
    }




    //Determine density
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        int density = metrics.densityDpi;

        if (density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH) {
            Log.d("Screen Density: ","HIGH");
        }
        else if (density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM) {
            Log.d("Screen Density: ","MEDIUM");
        }
        else if (density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW) {
            Log.d("Screen Density: ","LOW");
        }
        else if (density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH) {
            Log.d("Screen Density: ","XHIGH");
        }
        else if (density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH) {
            Log.d("Screen Density: ","XXHIGH");
        }
        else {
            Log.d("Screen Density: ","UNKNOWN_CATEGORY");
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for the same thing! I found 2 similar questons/answers:

[Getting ScreenLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998264/how-do-i-get-the-generalized-screen-size)

[Using ScreenLayout Bitmask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015094/determine-device-screen-category-small-normal-large-xlarge-using-code)

While all three questions are essentially the same, you really need both answers to get your result.

I used this code to get the layout size inside my Activity:

```
int layoutSize = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout;
layoutSize = layoutSize & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;
```

The first line will return the layout size, but it will be a number that is almost the maximum size of an `int`.

The second line will AND the layout size with the given mask. The mask has a value of 15 in decimal, or F in hex.

The value returned is between 0 and 3. The values corresponding to screen sizes, as well as the value of the size mask,  are defined as constants in the `android.content.res.Configuration` class: [Android Configruation Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE).

All you need to do after the previous 2 lines is to have some kind of a switch statement comparing the returned `layoutSize` with `Configuration`'s pre-defined values for `SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XXX`.

Hope this is not too late for you to use it. My problem was that I did not know how to ask the question in exact Android language. That is probably why the same question was, and probably should be, asked so many different ways.

Answer (score 2):

That's an old question, but I would like to share my way of solving this issue.

Create a *values-** variant matching each setup you wish to confirm programmatically, inside which you'll define the proper values describing the current configuration:

[image]

As you can see, the boolean value *is_landscape* exists both in *values* and *values-land*, therefore it is possible to safely access it via *R.bool.is_landscape*.

The only difference, though, is the value:

`getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_landscape);` evaluates to `true` in landscape mode, and `false` otherwise.

**Note**: of course that it is possible to use `getResources().getConfiguration().orientation` in order to get the current device orientation, though I chose to use this simple familiar case to make my example clear and straight forward.

It is important to understand that this technique is versatile, using which one can define a more complex values resource directory, ( e.g. *values-ldrtl-sw600dp-v23* ) to support a more specific configuration.

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup)getWindow().getDecorView();
LinearLayout content = (LinearLayout)view.getChildAt(0);
int id = content.getId();
```

The id tells you which layout you're using (assuming you set the id tag in the XML).

Comment: hmmm. I tried with my RelativeLayout view: `RelativeLayout content = (RelativeLayout)view.getChildAt(0);` and it causes a typecast exception: `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout`. Any idea why?