# How to check Tablet Size Programatically in Android

Tags: android, layout

Right now, I do this:

```
    if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {
        actionBar.removeAllTabs();

    } else {  // other stuff to do 

    }
```

However, I want this to prove true ONLY if it is 10"+ tablets, or XLarge.  Not 7 inch (e.g. Nexus 7).  I want the 7" to be same layout as phone.  Can I do this check pragmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE` with [`SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE):

```
if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE) {
    /* implementation */
}
```

If possible avoid using the deprecated `large` and `xlarge` qualifiers and use the new `sw<N>dp` qualifier. However, depending on your target audience and platform, you may need to rely on the older approach, or potentially a mix of both.

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid doing this in code, and instead make a resource-qualified folder for your layout defined for `sw720dp` (i.e. you should make your 10" layout under `res/layout-sw720dp`). Avoid using the `large` and `xlarge` qualifiers, and rely on the number of density-independent pixels available.

See this section on [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers) for more info.

Comment: The problem is, I have a `ViewPager` and Action Bar tabs that I can't control (remove) in XML without crashing the app.  I don't need them on large screens, but I do on small.  So if I did it that way as you say I get null pointer on the `ViewPager`.  Now, can I do this programatically using the density-independant qualifiers?

Comment: There are a few different ways you could do that...one hackish yet very easy way to do this that I saw [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7284958/321697) would be to make a boolean in your values.xml, and another in `res/values-sw720dp/values.xml`, where it's false in the first, and true in the second. Then in code, get the value of the boolean. If it's true, you're on a sw720dp device.

Comment: The second way would be to get the DisplayMetrics, get the pixel dimensions of the window area, divide it by (density / 160) (e.g. a 1920x1080 hdpi device would be (1080 / (240 / 160)) == (1080 / 1.5) == 720dp).

Comment: Very nice. I like the hackish way.  I will upvote your answer.  Marked the other guy correct because that is what I am using at the moment.