# Android: Disable screen rotation when screen smaller than x

Tags: android, cordova, rotation, screen-size

Anyone know how can I disable screen rotation in my Android app when screen is smaller than (for example) 480px?
I'm building app using phonegap witch will be targeted to tablet devices, but it's also possible to run it on smart-phones. Unfortunately application is only displayed properly when app is displayed in landscape orientation...

Comment: I did it, but I have to wait 8 hours (6 more) to post answer to my question ( I have < 100 rep...) on SO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe an 'if' controlled

setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

in the onCreate function?

Answer (score 4):

Did it! :)

Here is how (self explanatory):

```
int width;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
    width = display.getWidth();
    if(width <= 480) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }

}


@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if(width <= 480) {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }
}'
```

and few imports:

```
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.view.Display;'
```

Answer (score 0):

combining the solution of @Howard Hodson and in this thread [How to determine device screen size category (small, normal, large, xlarge) using code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015094/determine-device-screen-category-small-normal-large-xlarge-using-code)

I use this code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    disableLandscapeInSmallDevices();
}

private void disableLandscapeInSmallDevices() {
    if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
}
```