# Change dialog size in Android Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, dialog

How can I change dialog size for Android Facebook SDK? It's almost fullscreen which is OK for phone, but not OK for tablet. I would like to have different dialog size for tables and phones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone cares - Facebook doesn't support this out of the box. You *have* to hack the code with some special cases, using calculations similar to childofthehorn's to check if the device is tablet or not, and then resize it manually.

Answer (score 2):

Why not instantiate it, or the pieces you want, in a Fragment?

Here is the doc for Webview Fragments 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewFragment.html

Now Facebook does have some native Fragments integrated into their SDK, like the Picker Fragment: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/PickerFragment

This is what the webfragment would look like when you place it in your `Layout`:

```
 <fragment 
    android:id="@+id/webFragment"
    android:layout_width="150dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="my.proj.WebViewer"></fragment >
```

You should be able to Fragmentize what you need for Tablets. Justin Breitfeller posted this code on stackoverflow: 
[How to detect 7" Android tablet in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724338/how-to-detect-7-android-tablet-in-code)

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

float widthInInches = metrics.widthPixels / metrics.xdpi;
float heightInInches = metrics.heightPixels / metrics.ydpi

double sizeInInchesSquared = (widthInInches * widthInInches) + (heightInInches * heightInInches);
//0.5" buffer for 7" devices (6.5^2 = 42.25) (7.5^2 = 56.25)
boolean is7inchTablet = sizeInInchesSquared >= 42.25 && sizeInInchesSquared <= 56.25;
```

I have used this in the past to make a different view for 7" and above screens in the past effectively. Then, you can call a different layout using different fragments or having fragments change size dynamically to effectively fit a screen based on type.

It would be helpful if you gave us a bit more detail about what exactly you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

In the Android Facebook 3.0 SDK make sure the LoginActivity Activity declaration in your manifest looks like this:

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
```

Setting the theme like this still starts the facebook activity as a fullscreen activity, but the entire activity is transparent so it looks like only a dialog appears.

I guess this is more of a hack than anything else, but that's how Facebook does this in the Scrumptious sample project.

*****EDIT*****

If you're using version 4.x of the Facebook SDK you need to override and REPLACE the theme of the FacebookActivity in your AndroidManifest like so ::

```
        <activity
            tools:replace="android:theme"
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's still valid now, no transparent with facebook SDK 3.21.1 on Lollipop 5.0.2

Comment: Interesting.  This may have changed depending on the theme FB is using in their new SDK.  I assume you may have to do some work with theming, but can't be sure at the moment.  I will certainly find out when I get to updating the fb SDK in my apps.  In the meantime, if you find a solution please don't hesitate to share ;-)