# How should I define dimensions for phones with small and large screen size?

Tags: android, android-layout

I read the official guide on [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) but I still have some doubts on how I should implement it.

An activity of the application I'm writing simply contains few lines of text and I'd like to display bigger text on bigger screens.

I tried to produce different `dimens.xml` files but I cannot get it to work as expected.

I am testing my application on a 3.2" phone and on a 5" phone and I created two different files, one in the `values` folder and the other in the `values-normal` folder.
Unfortunately the effect I managed to achieve is that both the 3.2" and the 5" phone follows the settings I reported in the `values-normal` folder.

In which folder should I put the `dimens.xml` file for the phone with the bigger screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phones will use the resources that best match their size/density.  If both devices are currently taking their values from `values-normal` and you think that they shouldn't, try creating `values-small` for the smaller device and `values-large` for the larger device.

The groupings are only guidelines, so there aren't strict rules like "phones with screens >5" will always be at least `values-large`."

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7410370/85950) for a description of how to check the size category on your particular devices.  See ["How Android Finds the Best-matching Resource"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch) for a description of exactly how the matching process works.