# How do I enable a disabled (in xml) ListPreference object in .java code?

Tags: java, android, xml, listpreference

***EDIT 3***

Here's how I determine if the device is a tablet in `onCreate` for main `Activity`:

```
  public static boolean isTablet(Context ctx){
    return (ctx.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
        & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK
    )
        >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
  }
```

I don't know if that's a hack and not reliable, but in any event, I don't know how to use it in `onCreate` in the `Fragment` (below) because I don't know what `Context` to pass to `isATablet`.

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);Preference p = getPreferenceManager().findPreference("orientation");
    p.setEnabled(isTablet(????????????????));
```

***EDIT*** showing arrays as defined in `strings.xml` as requested:

```
<string-array name="modes">
    <item>0</item>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="indices">
    <item>Portrait</item>
    <item>Landscape</item>
    <item>Rotate</item>
</string-array>
```

*** END EDIT ***

**How do I `enable` this `ListPreference` object in `.java` code?**

```
<PreferenceCategory>
    <ListPreference
        android:key="orientation"
        android:title="Orientation (for tablets only)"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:summary="Lock in portrait or landscape mode or neither (allow rotation to determine)?"
        android:defaultValue="0"
        android:entries="@array/indices"
        android:entryValues="@array/modes"
        >
    </ListPreference>
</PreferenceCategory>
```

I can't make Android Studio 1.1.0 let me give it an `id`; but if there's a way, there's my solution--how do I do it?

***EDIT***

Workaround:

`android:enabled="true"`

```
if(isATablet) { // ***************************
  switch (preferences.getString(ORIENTATION, "0")) {
    case "0":
      setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
      break;
    case "1":
      setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
      break;
    case "2":
      setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
      break;
    default:
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bad orientation", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
else{ // ***************************
  editor = preferences.edit(); // ***************************
  editor.putString(ORIENTATION,"0"); // ***************************
  editor.commit(); // ***************************
  setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

}
```

Very lame. Please help!

Comment: Can you post your `@array/indices` and `@array/modes`?

Comment: I have a feeling I'm going about this wrong...

Comment: You want this preference to be enabled for tablets only?

Comment: Are you using the method described Here?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279111/determine-if-the-device-is-a-smartphone-or-tablet

Comment: @DanielNugent--no, but which method? (long link) What I want is to disallow rotation if the device doesn't have great enough "landscape height" (i.e., width) to display my entire UI, which is true for typical phones.  I use FIRST `isATablet` method found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015094/how-to-determine-device-screen-size-category-small-normal-large-xlarge-usin).

Comment: I think that would work too.  I direct linked to another way to do it in my answer!

Comment: I tried the 3 xml files approach but get error: `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeProDebugResources'.
> C:\Users\Dov\AndroidStudioProjects\KakuroCombosBuildVariants\app\src\main\res\values\values-xlarge.xml: Error: Duplicate resources: C:\Users\Dov\AndroidStudioProjects\KakuroCombosBuildVariants\app\src\main\res\values\values-xlarge.xml:bool/isTablet, C:\Users\Dov\AndroidStudioProjects\KakuroCombosBuildVariants\app\src\main\res\values\values-sw600dp.xml:bool/isTablet`

Comment: Hmm, not sure what's going on there.  I'd say go with your original method then, I'll remove the suggestion from the answer.  Aside from that, is the Java code to enable the preference working?

Comment: I have wrong directory structure for the 3 xml files. Hold off removing suggestion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78041/discussion-between-dslomer64-and-daniel-nugent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can just use the PreferenceManager and get the Preference based on the `key`.
See documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html#findPreference(java.lang.CharSequence))  and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#findPreference(java.lang.CharSequence)).

You could use the method [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279111/determine-if-the-device-is-a-smartphone-or-tablet/9308284#9308284) to determine if it's a tablet or not.

Then, it's just as simple as getting the preference, and enabling it if it's a tablet!

Edit:

In order to use your method and give it a valid `Context`, you could do it like this.  Note that I used a modified version of the code posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015094/how-to-determine-device-screen-size-category-small-normal-large-xlarge-usin/19256468#19256468) for the `isTablet()` method:

```
 public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

            Preference p = getPreferenceManager().findPreference("orientation");
            p.setEnabled(isTablet(getActivity()));
        }

        private boolean isTablet(Context context) {
            int screenLayout = context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout;
            screenLayout &= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;

            switch (screenLayout) {
                case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL:
                    return false;
                case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL:
                    return false;
                case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE:
                    return true;
                case 4: // Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE is API >= 9
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
        //...................
```

Comment: I'm at Barnes and Noble and the connection to chat just got severed.

Comment: @DSlomer64 I just updated the answer, this should work.  I used a variation that someone posted in order to make the `isTablet()` method a bit more readable and understandable.  I modified the code from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015094/how-to-determine-device-screen-size-category-small-normal-large-xlarge-usin/19256468#19256468

Comment: My last chat comment was going to be that `void` isn't valid return type for `onCreateView`.

Comment: And 'static' is causing error, too, in `class` definition. Are you using Android Studio? 1.1.0?

Comment: If I change return type to `View`, then AS gripes about `protected` and changes it to `public`. Fine by me, but what does it return? Not `null`; not `viewGroup` (which is results in `IllegalStateException: Fragment com.dslomer64.kakurocombosbuildvariants.SettingsFragment did not create a view`).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to incredible generosity of Daniel Nugent, here's what finally worked.

`preferences.xml` (don't enable or disable orientation):

```
    <PreferenceCategory>
        <ListPreference
            android:key="orientation"
            android:title="Orientation (for tablets only)"
            android:summary="Lock in portrait or landscape mode or neither (allow rotation to determine)?"
            android:defaultValue="0"
            android:entries="@array/indices"
            android:entryValues="@array/modes"
            >
        </ListPreference>
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

`SettingsFragment.java`:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
//  next two lines ****************************************************
    Preference p = getPreferenceManager().findPreference("orientation");
    p.setEnabled(isTablet(getActivity()));
//  Let java code enable or disable orientation ***********************
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
  }
  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
  }
  @Override
  public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

  }
}
```

`isTablet.java`:

```
  private boolean isTablet(Context context) {
    int screenLayout = context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout;
    screenLayout &= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;

    switch (screenLayout) {
      case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL:
        return false;
      case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL:
        return false;
      case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE:
        return true;
      case 4: // Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE is API >= 9
        return true;
      default:
        return false;
    }
  }
```