# Android "values-large-land" resource not loading

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

Any issue I've found related to this has always been resolved by correcting the layout files paths, and I'm pretty sure mine are correct.

I have a very simple layout made that is supposed to have a split view for large landscape devices.  So I have:

- layout/main.xml
- layout/main_twopane.xml
- values/main.xml
- values-large-land/main.xml

And I am loading a Nexus 7 Tablet in landscape (which is classified as a large device). The problem is it is always loading `main.xml` when according to the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html) what I have should load the two pane layout for large devices on landscape.

Here is the code:

layout/main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_catches"
    android:name="com.cohenadair.anglerslog.fragments.CatchesFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_catches"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

layout/main_twopane.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_catches"
        android:name="com.cohenadair.anglerslog.fragments.CatchesFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_catches"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_catch"
        android:name="com.cohenadair.anglerslog.fragments.CatchFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_catch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

values/main.xml

```
<resources>
    <item name="main_layout" type="layout">@layout/main</item>
    <bool name="has_two_panes">false</bool>
</resources>
```

values-large-land/main.xml

```
<resources>
    <item name="main_layout" type="layout">@layout/main_twopane</item>
    <bool name="has_two_panes">true</bool>
</resources>
```

The code that loads the layout, in `MainActivity.java`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

And in each individual fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View aView = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    // set the list's adapter
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Catch>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Logbook.getSharedLogbook().getCatches());
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    return aView;
}
```

And

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_catch, container, false);
}
```

Comment: Please post your Java code where you are loading this layout.

Comment: Hmm? I was under the impression the system automatically loaded the layout depending on the device size/orientation.  The documentation link in the question doesn't mention anything about loading the layout (if it does, I missed it).

Comment: "I was under the impression the system automatically loaded the layout depending on the device size/orientation" -- only in response to some Java code somewhere that is trying to load the layout, such as `setContentView()` on an `Activity`, or `inflate()` on a `LayoutInflater`.

Comment: Nexus 7 Tablet - I believe this has issues where it thinks it's a phone (size, telephony, the works) with certain update version. Please verify with this code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5016350/360211 Or an app such as [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jotabout.screeninfo)

Comment: @CommonsWare I've added the code that loads each layout. I think it's the right code.

Comment: Well the Nexus 9" worked, and the 7" said it was a phone, so you must be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is it is always loading main.xml

That is because you are telling Android to load `main`:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

If you want it to load `main_layout`, as your `values/...` stuff suggests, then change that to:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
```

I am not quite certain why you are going the layout resource alias approach here. It would be simpler, IMHO, for you to have `res/layout/main.xml` and `res/layout-large-land/main.xml`, then just request `R.layout.main` in your Java code, and dump the aliases. But, your aliases should work, but if and only if you request the alias.

Comment: I'm using aliases because eventually I'm going to be reusing fragments several times, and I don't want duplicate layout.xml files. Switching to `R.layout.main_layout` didn't seem to work. I'm going to change devices as a comment above mentioned a possible bug in the Nexus 7 Tablet.

Comment: This is your problem I think, either way, no need to switch devices, just verify it actually thinks it is large.

Comment: This is the solution. Thanks, CommonsWare. And Weston, you're right, Android does think the Nexus 7 simulator is a phone. Thank you for that.