# How to determine device screen size category (small, normal, large, xlarge) in order to test different screens in an application?

Tags: android, android-layout

In order to determine screen size categories of screens that are used by an Android application, I am using the code:

```
//Determine screen size
if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Large screen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Normal sized screen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Small sized screen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Screen size is neither large, normal or small", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

(code that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015094/how-to-determine-device-screen-size-category-small-normal-large-xlarge-usin))

But the result is weird... screens of densities from 480x800 to 1440x2560 are considered "normal size".

Tablets are considered "Screen size is neither large, normal or small"...

I did not find any small or large size indeed..

Is there another way to classify the screens? Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not confuse screen size and density.

For example, a device can have normal screen but high density (*hdp*)(**WVGA800 (480x800)**).

```
(getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
```

here you are getting the screen size.

You have to use this code to determine density:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int density = metrics.densityDpi;

if (density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "DENSITY_HIGH... Density is " + String.valueOf(density),  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else if (density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "DENSITY_MEDIUM... Density is " + String.valueOf(density),  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else if (density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "DENSITY_LOW... Density is " + String.valueOf(density),  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else if (density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "DENSITY_XHIGH... Density is " + String.valueOf(density),  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else if (density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "DENSITY_XXHIGH... Density is " + String.valueOf(density),  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else if (density==DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "DENSITY_XXXHIGH... Density is " + String.valueOf(density),  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Density is neither HIGH, MEDIUM OR LOW.  Density is " + String.valueOf(density),  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing for Android 3.2 or higher, those size groups are deprecated.

You should be using

- ldpi    0.75x
- mdpi    1.0x
- hdpi    1.5x
- xhdpi   2x
- xxhdpi  3x
- xxxhdpi 4x

And you can use `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density` to figure out which bucket is your current device using. (Corresponds to number besides X)

However, the density doesn't necessarily map to size of the screen.